# Is there any link between functional programming and strong typing?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, strong-typing, duck-typing

All of the "pure" functional languages are strong typed. Is there any link between those?

Comment: muscly fingers of functional programmers, as opposed to those weak ass fingers of imperative and dynamic programmers :)

Comment: You're going to have to define "pure".

Comment: So you have now a pure functional dynamic programming language: http://code.google.com/p/pure-lang/

Comment: @pyfunc: "Despite its name, PURE is not a pure functional language because it allows the user to change the value of a variable." — [PurePrimer1](http://code.google.com/p/pure-lang/wiki/PurePrimer1).  And it looks to me like printing/C bindings are also done impurely.  I *think* the reason purely functional languages tend to have type systems is that you need some mechanism of statically forbidding things like arbitrary printing; if you don't have static checks, then you either aren't purely functional or can't print at all.

Comment: there is a difference between strongly vs. weakly and statically vs. dynamically typed languages. those two characteristics are orthogonal.  I am not sure whether you really mean strongly typed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system I see no reason for pure language be limited to any particular combination... purity is just another dimension.

Comment: What do you mean by "strongly typed"? Is Python strongly typed because it does't implicitly convert things? Is C strongly typed because every expression is treated as if it were a statically known type? Is Java strongly typed because type conversions are checked to be reasonable either at compile time or at runtime? I'm sure we'd all agree that Haskell is "strongly typed", but which particular feature(s) of its type system are you considering when you ask whether there's a link between "strong typing" and pure functional programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercury (in which you can do functional programming, but is more of a pure logic programming language) actually has an explicit static purity system. Every predicate or function is statically known to be pure or impure (or semipure, but I'm not going to go into that in detail). Putting a call to an impure function inside a pure function (pure is the default) will result in an error detected at compile time.

It also has a static type system, in which the type of every expression/variable is statically known by the compiler, and type errors are detected at compile time. But the type system is completely independent of the purity system (in that you can have pure, impure, and semipure functions of any given type).

So we can imagine a different language with the same static purity system but in which the types of expressions/variables are not statically known, and may vary dynamically at runtime. One could even imagine such a language having "weak types" in the sense of PHP (i.e. the language will try to convert values such that operations that don't make sense on the value's type can actually be performed), or in the sense of C (i.e. you can convince the language to store values of one type in a variable the language will treat as if it were a different type).

One could also imagine a language in which the purity was not statically known but still enforced at runtime. The language would have to do something such as keeping track of whether it was in an pure call, and if so rejecting calls to impure primitive operations.

So in that sense, no there's no link between strong typing and pure programming.

However, languages which actually enforce purity (rather than merely encouraging it, as in Scala) have traditionally achieved this by static analysis. Indeed, one of the motivations for pure code is that it is much more susceptible to static analysis than code which is impure in arbitrary ways. A contrived example is that a function which takes a boolean argument and returns something can be known to return one of at most two results if it is pure; if it is **not known** to be pure then the language has to assume it might return something different at every single invocation.. And if you're interested in doing static analysis of your code and you have this static analysis system for enforcing purity, you might as well make it enforce type safety as well. So there's just "not that much call" for languages which enforce purity but don't have strong static type systems. I'm not aware of any that actually exist (there's not all that many languages that enforce purity at all, as far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

Non-trivial functional programming techniques make heavy use of first-class and higher-order functions. First-class functions are implemented as closures. Non-trivial use of first-class functions and closures is only sane when you have garbage collection. Efficient and reliable garbage collection requires memory safety (which I assume you mean by "strongly typed"). So there you go.

Purity doesn't really matter for that.

Answer (score 2):

"Pure" functional languages are those which enforce referential transparency. The enforcement could be static (via the type system), or it could be dynamic (e.g. a runtime failure). I'm guessing you mean "statically typed" when you say "strongly typed"...

Sincbe the community from which typed, pure functional programming emerged is separately issued in reducing runtime failures and making programming safer adding purity without type enforcement -- such that runtime failure is still an option -- is incongruous.

So its no suprise you see types and effect typing going together with purity-by-default: it is all about reducing runtime failures.